# while-mousedown

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to solve this problem.

When the mouse button is pressed down on the max button the variable `max` should increase by one. When I hold down the min button the `max` variable should decrease but it's not working for me.

How do I get this to work?

```
<body>


<button id="max" onmousedown="max()" >max</button>
<input id="num" type="number" disabled="disabled" value="0">
<button id="min" onmousedown="min()">min</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function max()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("num").value
  if (x<100) {var max= document.getElementById("num").value++;}
}

function min()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("num").value
  if (x>0) {var max= document.getElementById("num").value--;}
}

</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tAh6Q/2/)

A few things:

1 - I've removed the inline events from your input tags.

2 - In order to get the intervals to work correctly you need to have a reference to that process. In my example `minInterval` and `maxInterval` allow me to call `clearInterval` `onmouseup`.

3 - For these to work correctly you'll need to run the script after the DOM is loaded/ready, so put the code near the end of your `body` tag.

4 - The value of `speed` is basically how quickly you want the intervals to be ran.

**HTML**

```
<button id="max" >max</button>
<input id="num" type="number" disabled="disabled" value="0">
<button id="min">min</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var min = document.getElementById("min"),
    max = document.getElementById("max"),
    num = document.getElementById("num"),
    speed = 10,
    minInterval, maxInterval;

min.onmousedown = function(){

    minInterval = setInterval(function(){
        num.value--;
    }, speed);
};

min.onmouseup = function(){
    clearInterval(minInterval);
};

max.onmousedown = function(){
    maxInterval = setInterval(function(){
       num.value++;
    }, speed);
};

max.onmouseup = function(){
    clearInterval(maxInterval);
};
```

**Helpful links:**

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

[clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval)

Comment: but i want the num.value between 100 and 0 i cant do it with the loop i don't know why ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
function max()
{
    var numElement = document.getElementById("num");
    var x= numElement.value
    var fnc = function ()
    {
        if (x<100){
        document.getElementById("num").value = x;
        x++;
    }    
    var i = setInterval(fnc, 100);
    fnc(); 
    document.onmouseup = function ()
    {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}   


function min()
{
    var numElement = document.getElementById("num");
    var x= numElement.value
    var fnc = function ()
    {
        if (x>0){
        document.getElementById("num").value = x;
        x--;
    }    
    var i = setInterval(fnc, 100);
    fnc(); 
    document.onmouseup = function ()
    {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}
```